# Where can you find Mint 19.3 32 Bit mouse pointers?

Tags: linux-mint, mouse, desktop-environment

Running Mint 19.3 32 Bit. I would like more mouse pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Mouse pointers are found at:
Menu  /
'Appearence' /
'Themes'  (default tab) /
'Icons' tab

(Names translated from french, maybe not totally correct)

I use 'Oxygen' pointers, install with:
sudo apt-get install oxygen*

Eventually search 'linux mouse pointers' with your favorite tool

Comment: Thanks Luc. I actually can use 'Oxygen' on my 64 Bit Mint. But they will not work on my 32 Bit Mint. As for 'Themes', I can get a lot of mouse pointers on my 64 Bit Mint. But I only have 2 (Black or White) to choose from on my 32 Bit Mint. Go figure. Thanks again for taking the time Luc.

Comment: You're welcome :-)

Comment: @SteelDust Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved.

Comment: I used sudo snap refresh firefox, and it said no updates were available.

Comment: Why use snap  ? Use sudo apt-get install firefox